# php want to understand foreach and if result on particular example

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

Have this array

```
$date_and_currency_array =    Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [number_of_input_row] => 1
        [date_day] => 01
        [date_month] => 12
        [date_year] => 2013
        [currency] => BGN
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [number_of_input_row] => 2
        [date_day] => 01
        [date_month] => 12
        [date_year] => 2012
        [currency] => DKK
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [number_of_input_row] => 3
        [date_day] => 11
        [date_month] => 12
        [date_year] => 2013
        [currency] => ILS
    )

)
```

Then

```
foreach ( $date_and_currency_array as $i => $date_and_currency_value ) {

echo $date_and_currency_value['date_year']. ' __$date_and_currency_value[date_year]<br>';

if ($date_and_currency_value['date_year'] = 2013) {
echo '2013 ....<br>';

}//if

}//foreach
```

Here `if ($date_and_currency_value['date_year'] = 2013) {` expect to echo `2013` only 2 times, because there are only two `[date_year] => 2013`. But `2013` echo 3 times.

Please advice why `2013` echo 3 times.

Thanks to replies. My stupid negligence. Need to rest

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator. Use  `==` which is a comparison operator.

Comment: Sidenote: Careful with using 2x leading underscores `__$date` PHP may confuse it as a [`constructor`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

Comment: Why the downvote? The OPs question is clear & with code examples. Ive seen worse so +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because your assigning instead of comparing as you missed a `=` in your if statement

`if ($date_and_currency_value['date_year'] == 2013) {`

Answer (score 1):

in this `if ($date_and_currency_value['date_year'] = 2013)` you should add two `==`  that is `if ($date_and_currency_value['date_year'] == 2013)`

Answer (score 0):

As here you have used single '=' condition will be true for each time the loop rotates so as answer given above you need to use '==' so that it exactly notifies compiler to compare as single '='is assignment operator.

so try out

```
    if($date_and_currency_value['date_year'] == 2013)
    {
            echo "something";
    }
```